# Unable to install and load packages

Tags: r, installation, package, rstudio, netcdf

I have recently downloaded R and Rstudio onto my computer.

When I try to install the package ncdf (or any package) I get the following messages:

```
> install.packages("ncdf")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Talos/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/ncdf_1.6.7.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 358300 bytes (349 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 349 Kb

package ‘ncdf’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Talos\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKuMfwR\downloaded_packages

> load("ncdf")
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
  cannot open compressed file 'ncdf', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

I have tried going to the folder and manually unzipping the file, which seems to make no difference at all.

What is the solution to this so that I can install, load, and use packages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `library` not `load`. Please read the help files `? library` and `? load` for further information.

Comment: Oh man. You've got to love the SO voting system. +1 for the correct answer.